# How do I set labels above their respected elements with this styled input?

Tags: html, input, label, bootstrap-5

I have styled inputs (I'll put the CSS here, which has ultimately got too complicated and I have lost track of where I need to remove and fix). I am trying to get labels to fit above my input, my select options and my output.

```css
/* ================== */
/* === GLOBAL CSS === */
/* ================== */

/* Input Placeholder and Select Text Size */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input[type="number"]::-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input[type="number"]:-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input[type="number"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

select.form-select {
  font-size: 75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select.form-select,
input.reset_form {
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
}

.form-group .row .col:first-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.form-group .row .col:last-child {
  width: auto;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-group .row {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-group .row .col:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}

label.form-label {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

/* Set height of input boxes */

.form-control.input-rounded-start {
  height: 34px;
}

.input-group-text {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}




/* ================= */
/* === LOCAL CSS === */
/* ================= */


td.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

td.form-group label.form-label {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem;
}

.input-group select {
  max-width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}

.row-input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.row-input .form-control {
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 60%;
}

.input-group select {
  width: 15%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.output-group {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.select-input {
  width: 10% !important;
}

.output-group {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  font-style: italic;
}

.input-label-container {
  position: relative;
}

.label-above {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.3em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<section class="container border border-primary bg_cont mb-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
      <div class="card shadow-sm p-3 mt-1 mb-1">
        <span></span>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row mb-3 row-input">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="input" class="form-label d-none d-sm-inline">Input</label>
              <div class="input-group p-1">
                <input type="number" name="" id="" class="reset_form formCheck maxAllow form-control input-rounded-start">
                <!-- Label Needs To Go Here -->
                <select class="form-select select-input" name="unitsVelocity" id="units">
                  <option value="c" selected>c</option>
                </select>
                <!-- Label Needs To Go Here -->
                <div class="form-control output-group" id="value">
                  *stuff*</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--          More stuff  -->
</section>
```

The labels, if I put them there, just break the input and select boxes. (picture below).
I know I need to get these into columns but I want the output to look like the picture below except with labels above the elements.

I've tried manipulating columns etc, but this ultimately ends up breaking the boxes.

[image]

I have numerous CSS to keep my inputs the way I want them (check snippet).

The lavel-above and container idea was good, but it didn't put the labels above without breaking the input box.

This is the best I have at the moment... any ideas would be wonderful. I am using Bootstrap 5.2

Summary: I would like labels above my select box and my output box the same way I have a label above my input box. I want to keep the same style for all my input, select and output, but just with labels above.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5, AFAIK, doesn't have a built-in way to handle labels above inputs *within input groups*. That said, if you carefully follow the documentation, you can achieve something quite similar with floating labels and input groups.

Here is a working snippet, with **no additional CSS**.

Note the use of `.form-floating`, placeholders and the placement of the labels **after** the inputs, as per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="velocity" aria-label="velocity" placeholder="Velocity (v)">
      <label for="velocity">Velocity (v)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <select class="form-control form-select" id="velocityUnits" placeholder="Velocity Units">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
      </select>
      <label for="velocityUnits">Velocity Units</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <span class="input-group-text form-control" id="gammaFactor">Gamma Factor (y)</span>
      <label for="gammaFactor">Output</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following snippet fix your dropdown:

```css
/* ================== */
/* === GLOBAL CSS === */
/* ================== */

/* Input Placeholder and Select Text Size */

input[type="number"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input[type="number"]::-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input[type="number"]:-moz-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input[type="number"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

select.form-select {
  font-size: 75%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select.form-select,
input.reset_form {
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
}

.form-group .row .col:first-child {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.form-group .row .col:last-child {
  width: auto;
}

.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-group .row {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-group .row .col:first-child {
  flex: 1;
}

label.form-label {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

/* Set height of input boxes */

.form-control.input-rounded-start {
  height: 34px;
}

.input-group-text {
  height: 34px;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
}




/* ================= */
/* === LOCAL CSS === */
/* ================= */


td.form-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

td.form-group label.form-label {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 75%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem 0 0 0.25rem;
}

.input-group select {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 0.25rem 0.25rem 0;
}

.row-input {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.row-input .form-control {
  height: calc(1.5em + 0.75rem + 2px);
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
}

.input-group input {
  width: 60%;
}

.input-group select {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.output-group {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.output-group {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #555;
  font-style: italic;
}

.input-label-container {
  position: relative;
}

.label-above {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.3em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<section class="container border border-primary bg_cont mb-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
      <div class="card shadow-sm p-3 mt-1 mb-1">
        <span></span>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row mb-3 row-input">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label for="input" class="form-label d-none d-sm-inline">Input</label>
              <div class="input-group p-1">
                <input type="number" name="" id="" class="reset_form formCheck maxAllow form-control input-rounded-start">
                <!-- Label Needs To Go Here -->
                <select class="form-select select-input" name="unitsVelocity" id="units">
                  <option value="a">a</option>
                  <option value="b">b</option>
                  <option value="c" selected>c</option>
                </select>
                <!-- Label Needs To Go Here -->
                <div class="form-control output-group" id="value">
                  *stuff*</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--          More stuff  -->
</section>
```